# Is there a way to do this kind of casting in a c# predicate

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to create a generic method that will return a predicate to find elements in an XML document.

Basically something like this:

```
private static Func<XElement, bool> GetPredicate<T>(Criterion criterion)
{
    switch (criterion.CriteriaOperator)
    {
        case CriteriaOperator.Equal:
            return x => (T)x.Attribute(criterion.PropertyName) == 
                (T)(criterion.PropertyValue);
        case CriteriaOperator.GreaterThan:
            return x => (T)x.Attribute(criterion.PropertyName) > 
                (T)(criterion.PropertyValue);
        case CriteriaOperator.GreaterThanOrEqual:
            return x => (T)x.Attribute(criterion.PropertyName) >= 
                (T)(criterion.PropertyValue);
        case CriteriaOperator.LessThan:
            return x => (T)x.Attribute(criterion.PropertyName) < 
                (T)(criterion.PropertyValue);
        case CriteriaOperator.LessThanOrEqual:
            return x => (T)x.Attribute(criterion.PropertyName) <= 
                (T)(criterion.PropertyValue);
        case CriteriaOperator.NotEqual:
            return x => (T)x.Attribute(criterion.PropertyName) != 
                (T)(criterion.PropertyValue);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Criteria Operator not supported.");
    }
}
```

Only thing is that this doesn't compile. The problem is on the `(T)x.Attribute(criterion.PropertyName)` part where the compiler indicates:

> Cannot cast expression of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute' to type
>   'T'

Currently I have two methods that are identical except that one casts to double and the other one to decimal. I would really like not to have that kind of duplication.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Is a custom class that contains the data for the boolean expression. PropertyName is a string that represents the attribute name in the xml node I'm matching against and PropertyValue is an object with the value I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [XAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300510.aspx) defines several [conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986944.aspx). However,when casting to a generic type parameter `T`, these operators are not taken into consideration.

What you can do is construct the lambda expression at runtime as follows:

```
private static Func<XElement, bool> GetPredicate<T>(Criterion criterion)
{
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(XElement), "arg");
    var name = Expression.Constant((XName)criterion.PropertyName);
    var attr = Expression.Call(arg, "Attribute", null, name);
    var left = Expression.Convert(attr, typeof(T));
    var right = Expression.Constant(criterion.PropertyValue, typeof(T));

    Expression body;

    switch (criterion.CriteriaOperator)
    {
    case CriteriaOperator.Equal:
        body = Expression.Equal(left, right);
        break;
    case CriteriaOperator.GreaterThan:
        body = Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentException("Criteria Operator not supported.");
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<XElement, bool>>(body, arg).Compile();
}
```

*Usage:*

```
var f = GetPredicate<int>(new Criterion("documentversion", CO.GreaterThan, 8));
var g = GetPredicate<string>(new Criterion("documentid", CO.Equal, "DOC-5X"));
var h = GetPredicate<double>(new Criterion("documentprice", CO.Equal, 85.99d));
```

Comment: It almost worked. For a string type it worked fine but, for the double one it failed on the var right = Expression.Constant(criterion.PropertyValue, typeof(T)) with an ArgumentException "Argument types do not match".

Comment: In this case `T` doesn't match the type of the value in `criterion.PropertyValue`. I've added a few working examples.

Answer (score 1):

There are no [implicit or explicit conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986944.aspx) to an arbitrary type `T`.  The only conversions allowed from [`XAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.aspx) to another type are explicit and to these types:

- [`Boolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350766.aspx)
- [`Nullable<Boolean>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342869.aspx)
- [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351725.aspx)
- [`Nullable<DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302294.aspx)
- [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909303.aspx)
- [`Nullable<DateTimeOffset>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909378.aspx)
- [`Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357643.aspx)
- [`Nullable<Decimal>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357051.aspx)
- [`Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338730.aspx)
- [`Nullable<Double>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354044.aspx)
- [`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301657.aspx)
- [`Nullable<Guid>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337514.aspx)
- [`Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358993.aspx)
- [`Nullable<Int32>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358878.aspx)
- [`Int64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345396.aspx)
- [`Nullable<Int64>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337557.aspx)
- [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343526.aspx)
- [`Nullable<Single>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300467.aspx)
- [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339184.aspx)
- [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344160.aspx)
- [`Nullable<TimeSpan>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154727.aspx)
- [`UInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341815.aspx)
- [`Nullable<UInt32>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338735.aspx)
- [`UInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291917.aspx)
- [`Nullable<UInt64>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300661.aspx)

You'll have to create overloads that take one of the above types, and limit the calls to one of those.

Answer (score 1):

If you just replace your casts to `T` with casts to `dynamic`, it would work then.  I wouldn't feel bad about throwing away type safety here since you probably can't ensure that the stuff in the XML attributes is the right type anyway -- so type safety was an illusion all along.

Comment: Although this was a very promising and simple option it didn't work. Works grate for the Equal and Not Equal options but, for the others there's always an exception that string (the Attribute value) cannot be compared with double (the PropertyValue value).

Answer (score 0):

What is `T` supposed to be? An `XAttribute` can't be converted to it unless there's some kind of constraint on the generic. In any case, you probably want to get `Attribute().Value`, which is a string. Then you can do a comparison. What is the type of `criterion.PropertyValue`?

If your XML contains primitives like numbers, you can't just cast a string straight to a number. You need to use methods like `double.TryParse()`. Unfortunately there's no way I know of to constrain a generic to have a `TryParse` method. If there were, you would be able to say `T.TryParse`. But there is no way, so you can't. Generics probably won't help you with this.

Comment: The XAttribute class defines several [conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986944.aspx).

Comment: @dtb Wow that's extremely useful. Thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to help the OP here.

Comment: @Tesserex: Actually, it does.  There are explicit casts defined to other types, you can't cast to an arbitrary type.  Your suggestion would just circumvent the code that's in `XAttribute` already which handles XML-specific formatting for certain types and would possibly break.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare two `T`s using `==`, but `object.Equals()` should work.

To do the conversion, you could use [`Convert.ChangeType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx):

```
case CriteriaOperator.Equal:
    return x => object.Equals(
        Convert.ChangeType(x.Attribute(criterion.PropertyName).Value, typeof(T)),
        criterion.PropertyValue);
```

The problem with this is that XML uses different rules for conversions in some cases (e.g. `Double.PositiveInfinity` is represented as `INF`).

To solve this, you could use [the `XmlConvert` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.aspx), which is used internally by the conversion operators. Except it doesn't have a “generic” method like `Convert.ChangeType()`, so you would have to create your own:

```
private static object Convert(string value, Type targetType)
{
    if (targetType == typeof(double))
        return XmlConvert.ToDouble(value);

    …

    throw new ArgumentException();
}

…

case CriteriaOperator.Equal:
    return x => object.Equals(
        Convert(x.Attribute(criterion.PropertyName).Value, typeof(T)),
        criterion.PropertyValue);
```

Comment: This doesn't really attack the problem for things that aren't equality checks, like the comparison operators.

Comment: You're right. I didn't think of that. Although I think many of the types in question implement the non-generic `IComparable`, so that would take care of that.

Answer (score -1):

Add `XAttribute` constrait on generic method:

```
 GetPredicate<T>(Criterion criterion) where T : XAttribute
```

Comment: -1 The problem is that `XAttribute` doesn't have explicit conversions to an arbitrary type `T`.  The above won't solve the problem

Comment: @RedHat: This is not exactly the intent. The idea is that the predicate be something like x => x.Attribute("documentversion") > 8 or in a different case x => x.Attribute("documentid") == "DOC-5X" or event x => x.Attribute("documentprice") <= "85.99".